# Axiom of pairing for equivalent sets

Tags: logic, axioms

A teacher of logic in my university gave us the following definition of axiom of pairing which differs from Wikipedia's one:

$\forall x\forall y(\lnot x=y \to \exists p(x \in p\ \&\ y \in p\ \&\ \forall z(z \in p \to (z = x \lor z = y))))$.

At the exam he asked me why do we need the $\lnot x=y$ condition and I didn't manage to find any reason. He asked me, if we can get the set $\{ a, b\}$ where $a = b$ and I gave him a way to do that with some usages of other Zermelo–Fraenkel axioms. Then he asked whether $\{ a, a\}$ equals to $\{ a \}$. I said "yes, judging by the definition of set equality". He asked: "So what's the deal with the $\lnot x=y$ condition then?" and I was back to square one. So now I'm interested what's really the deal with it?

P.S. I passed the exam

Comment: Most times I've seen it, there wasn't this condition...

Comment: This would be weird teaching, but maybe Max's comment was the whole point... we don't need it? Maybe?

Comment: @Max, yeah, but he said that without this condition, it's not right. That's what bends me.

Comment: Speculation: he's deliberately weakening the axiom because we only need it for pairs $x\ne y$. If $x=y$ then the other axioms already tell us that $\{x\}$ exists. (Or at least I assume they do.) But that wouldn't explain why he thinks we need the condition so perhaps ignore this.

Comment: @RJM, it's hard to ignore something that makes this theory correct :) Why $\{ a, a \}$, got this way, is a problem?

Comment: Well Prof. Weiss in "An introduction to set theory" and Jech in "Set Theory" have a $\forall x, \forall y$ clause, without the $\neg x=y$ condition, so it can't be "not right" without this condition. As RJM points out, other axioms are enough to tell us that $\{x\}$ exists, so maybe your teacher wanted a "minimalist" axiom system, but then, he would have removed the axiom of pairing itself, which is unnecessary (in ZF, not in Z though)

Comment: @Max, okay, I will ask that the next time I see him to make it clear and will write his answer here :) Thank you for preparing me for the question!

Comment: @Max: can you give a reference or other evidence for your claim that the pairing axiom is unnecessary in ZF?

Comment: As I expect you observed to  your teacher, if you have the axiom of comprehension (aka. separation) and the axiom of power sets, then you have the existence of singleton sets $\{x\} = \{y \in \Bbb{P}(x) \mid y = x \}$, so it doesn't change ZF to add the proposed condition to the pairing axiom, but there is no need to do so. From the way you describe it, your teacher is just winding you up.

Comment: @RobArthan: Infinity+Replacement trivially imply Pairing, since you can just take your infinite set and replace one element with $x$ and all the other elements with $y$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: that sounds convincing, but I'd be grateful for a reference, if you know of one.

Comment: @RobArthan Alternatively, without the axiom of infinity, as soon as you know that there exists some set (which is often taken to be implicit as part of the logic), the power set of its power set will have at least two elements, and you can continue as in Eric Wofsey's comment, sending one element (for example $\varnothing$ to $x$ and all the others to $y$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: thanks. I am still interested in a reference because (I believe) the pairing axiom is necessary if you drop the axiom of replacement.

Comment: @RobArthan : I don't know if this counts as a reference, but Wikipedia mentions it. They must have references on the bottom of the page for that. I have a few books on elementary set theory, I can look them up if that's nt enough

Answer (score 3):

The $\neg x=y$ condition is completely unnecessary, and in fact is usually *not* included in the presentation of the ZF axioms (I have actually personally never seen it included).  As you have observed, in the presence of the other ZF axioms, it does not make any difference whether you include $\neg x=y$.  If you have no other axioms, including $\neg x=y$ gives you a weaker axiom, but I don't know of any context in which it is desirable to have this weaker axiom instead of the stronger version without it.

In sum, the standard answer to your teacher's question is "we don't".  If he has some other answer in mind, then it is something peculiar to his tastes or to something unusual you did in your course.